# How to edit specific lines from a text file and write them to a new file in Python?

Tags: python

my objective is to read a text file which looks something like this:

```
DI00        =DI
Logic0      =OFF
Logic1      =ON
DI01        =DI
Logic0      =OFF
Logic1      =ON
```

and it goes on until DI11. I want to edit this file, and write it to a new text file which will look like this:

```
DI00        =DOOR1
Logic0      =Door Open
Logic1      =Door Closed
DI01        =Camera1
Logic0      =CameraOn
Logic1      =CameraOff
```

I have tried a few things and nothing seems to work. I know it is just a simple block of code which someone can write for me in two minutes. The major problem is that the same line appears more than once, and it needs to be edited differently every time. Remember, I do not want to edit the file in place. I must write to a new one.

Here is what I have:

import fileinput

def IOConfig(siteLocation, siteName, timeServer, ip, mac):

```
for line in fileinput.FileInput("ik2210_vanilla.txt",inplace=1):
    line = line.replace("MOD_LOC=", "MOD_LOC=" + str(siteLocation))
    line = line.replace("MOD_NAME=", "MOD_NAME=" + str(siteName))
    line = line.replace("TIME_SERVER    =", "TIME_SERVER    =" + str(timeServer))
    line = line.replace("NET_IP     =192.168.127.254", "NET_IP      =" + str(ip))
    line = line.replace("NET_MAC        =192.168.127.254", "NET_MAC     =" + str(mac))  
    line = line.replace("Logic0     =OFF", "Logic0      =Door Open")

    print line,
```

IOConfig("David's Office", "David's Test Site", "10.140.140.999", "192.168.123.456", "00-90-E8-31-D8-44")

There is some extra code here but the issue is the last line.replace replaces all the logic0 = Off's. I will post my second attempt which tries to write to a new file.

```
import re

rf = open("ik2210_vanilla.txt", "r")
wf = open("test#1", "w")

lines = rf.readlines()
for lines[2] in lines:
wf.write(str("Logic1    =Door Open"))
wf.write(str(lines))

rf.close()
wf.close()
```

Here I am trying to change the third line of the file and write it to my new file. But it's not working.

Comment: "*I know it is just a simple block of code which someone can write for me in two minutes.*". That's not what StackOverflow is for.

Comment: That's not what I meant, honestly. I have tried! I have some code which I have written already but it edits the file in place and I get stuck where the same line appears more than once. the line = line.replace("..","...") changes every line with that description.

Comment: Then show us the code that you have tried, you will get much better responses that way;).

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. How do I post the code within the same thread? It is too long to add to the comments.

Comment: @DMitch: you can edit your question itself (you should see an `edit` link under the tag "Python" below the last line of your question, currently "I also need to know what to import").